# Most efficient way to sort parallel arrays in a restricted-feature language

Tags: algorithm, sorting, scripting

The environment:  I am working in a proprietary scripting language where there is no such thing as a user-defined function.  I have various loops and local variables of primitive types that I can create and use.

I have two related arrays, "times" and "values".  They both contain floating point values.  I want to numerically sort the "times" array but have to be sure that the same operations are applied on the "values" array.  What's the most efficient way I can do this without the benefit of things like recursion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You could maintain an index table and sort the index table instead.**

This way you will not have to worry about times and values being consistent.

And whenever you need a sorted value, you can lookup on the sorted index.

And if in the future you decided there was going to be a third value, the sorting code will not need any changes.

Here's a sample in C#, but it shouldn't be hard to adapt to your scripting language:

```
static void Main() {

    var r = new Random();

    // initialize random data
    var index = new int[10];      // the index table
    var times = new double[10];   // times 
    var values = new double[10];  // values

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        index[i] = i;
        times[i] = r.NextDouble();
        values[i] = r.NextDouble();
    }

    // a naive bubble sort
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)

            // compare time value at current index
            if (times[index[i]] < times[index[j]]) {

                // swap index value (times and values remain unchanged)
                var temp = index[i];
                index[i] = index[j];
                index[j] = temp;
            }

    // check if the result is correct
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(times[index[i]]);

    Console.ReadKey();

}
```

Note: I used a naive bubble sort there, watchout. In your case, an insertion sort is probably a good candidate. Since you don't want complex recursions.

Answer (score 2):

Just take your favourite sorting algorithm (e.g. Quicksort or Mergesort) and use it to sort the "values" array. Whenever two values are swapped in "values", also swap the values with the same indices in the "times" array.

So basically you can take any fast sorting algorithm and modify the swap() operation so that elements in both arrays are swapped.

Comment: He'll probably want to inline that swap(), because the language he is using doesn't allow user-defined functions.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Bottom-Up mergesort at Algorithmist](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_merge_sort).  It's a non-recursive way of performing a mergesort.  The version presented there uses function calls, but that can be inlined easily enough.

Like martinus said, every time you change a value in one array, do the exact same thing in the parallel array.

Here's a C-like version of a stable-non-recursive mergesort that makes no function calls, and uses no recursion.

```
const int arrayLength = 40;
float times_array[arrayLength];
float values_array[arrayLength];

// Fill the two arrays....

// Allocate two buffers
float times_buffer[arrayLength];
float values_buffer[arrayLength];
int blockSize = 1;

while (blockSize <= arrayLength)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (i < arrayLength-blockSize)
    {
        int begin1 = i;
        int end1 = begin1 + blockSize;
        int begin2 = end1;
        int end2 = begin2 + blockSize;

        int bufferIndex = begin1;
        while (begin1 < end1 && begin2 < end2)
        {
            if ( values_array[begin1] > times_array[begin2] )
            {
                times_buffer[bufferIndex] = times_array[begin2];
                values_buffer[bufferIndex++] = values_array[begin2++];
            }
            else
            {
                times_buffer[bufferIndex] = times_array[begin1];
                values_buffer[bufferIndex++] = values_array[begin1++];
            }
        }
        while ( begin1 < end1 )
        {
            times_buffer[bufferIndex] = times_array[begin1];
            values_buffer[bufferIndex++] = values_array[begin1++];
        }
        while ( begin2 < end2 )
        {
            times_buffer[bufferIndex] = times_array[begin2];
            values_buffer[bufferIndex++] = values_array[begin2++];
        }

        for (int k = i; k < i + 2 * blockSize; ++k)
        {
            times_array[k] = times_buffer[k];
            values_array[k] = values_buffer[k];
        }

        i += 2 * blockSize;
    }
    blockSize *= 2;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I wouldn't suggest writing your own sorting routine, as the sorting routines provided as part of the Java language are well optimized.

The way I'd solve this is to copy the code in the java.util.Arrays class into your own class i.e. org.mydomain.util.Arrays.  And add some comments telling yourself not to use the class except when you must have the additional functionality that you're going to add.  The Arrays class is quite stable so this is less, less ideal than it would seem, but it's still less than ideal.  However, the methods you need to change are private, so you've no real choice.

You then want to create an interface along the lines of:

`public static interface SwapHook {

void swap(int a, int b);

}`

You then need to add this to the sort method you're going to use, and to every subordinate method called in the sorting procedure, which swaps elements in your primary array.  You arrange for the hook to get called by your modified sorting routine, and you can then implement the SortHook interface to achieve the behaviour you want in any secondary (e.g. parallel) arrays.

HTH.